# HM10 firmware v540 not able to scan all Bluetooth modules

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I am using HM10 Bluetooth with firmware v540. I fired AT+DISC? in Arduino and only able to discover surrounding HM10 Bluetooth devices. i.e. not able to discover other Bluetooth devices, other than HM10 devices.

Firmware version below v530 has AT+FILT0, which is able to find all BLE modules. It has been removed since v530. Does it mean starting from v530, it is only able to discover HM10 bluetooth modules?

[Original post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/28156/hm10-firmware-v540-not-able-to-scan-all-bluetooth-modules)